# What does Jerry take before going to bed?

Tags: westworld-tv

In episode 1 of season 3 of *Westworld*, Jerry opens up a circular container and take a piece of something from inside, what is it that he ate shortly before going to bed?

[image: hands opening a tiny container]

Comment: We didn’t get a definitive explanation (and who knows if we will) but I thought it was some sort of sleep aid, possibly linked to the “implants” they mentioned a couple of times

Comment: Yeah, likely. They way they gave a close up shoot and how fancy it looks made me very curious

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a mockup website, Incite Inc makes this medicine and sells them.

> MEDICAL ADVANCEMENTS
>
> Finally, you can start feeling better.
>
> First, it was leeches and blood-letting. Then, it was pill popping and mood-stabilizing. Put away the blunt instrument and choose precision backed by insight into what makes you, you— and happy. Incite’s revolutionary tab technology taps into the olfactory nerve for direct access to your limbic system. Once placed in the mouth, these fully dissolvable limbic tabs transmit
>   a digital code to the brain, which is immediately translated into electrical impulses.
>
> Safe and 100% effective, these impulses generate a precise and specifically tailored sensation without any negative side effects. All it takes is a small, painless metal implant that is carefully contoured to the roof of your mouth, which pairs instantly to Incite’s ID8 app. Each fully customizable expericnce goes far beyond the simple upper / downer dichotomy of the early 2000s, allowing you to leave your cares behind with a Mellow Sunset or skyrocket your work ethic with a Soaring Eagle.

[image: screenshot of the above, with two little boxes of the medicine]

Comment: Which mock-up website?

Comment: https://inciteinc.com/

Comment: What is the simple upper/downer dichotomy of the early 2000s?